# How to reuse an instance of a custom datatype inside xml view?

Tags: sapui5

Is there a way to reuse a custom datatype object for multiple controls inside a xml view? In a JS view i have the possibility to first create a type and then reuse this type for multiple controls:

```
let oPowerType = new Power({decimals : 0, emptyString : null}); //Custom Datatype derived from sap.ui.model.SimpleType 

let oInputA = new sap.m.Input({
                            value : {
                                path : "model>powerA",
                                type : oPowerType
                            });
                            
let oInputB = new sap.m.Input({
                            value : {
                                path : "model>powerB",
                                type : oPowerType
                            });
```

How can I achieve this in a xml view? If I do the following, for each control a new object from type Power is created (which is not that smart, as it could be reused instead):

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m" 
    controllerName="mynamespace.controller.MainView"
    core:require="{Power : 'mynamespace/model/type/Power'}">

    <Input id="InputA" value="{
                            path : 'model>powerA', 
                            type : 'Power', 
                            formatOptions : {
                                decimals : 0, 
                                emptyString : null
                            }}" />
                            
    <Input id="InputB" value="{
                            path : 'model>powerA', 
                            type : 'Power', 
                            formatOptions : {
                                decimals : 0,
                                emptyString : null
                            }}" />
</mvc:View>
```

Any help or advise is welcome! :)

Comment: I guess it's cheap to create such small objects. If you use the standard UI5 types directly in XML it works very much the same.

Comment: @Marc You may be right. I didn't thought of it this way. It still seems not optimal to me but maybe there is no other way to do it in XML...